# Creating a "netbeans property" style dialog box

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, dialog

I've been trying to create a GUI using netbeans, that includes a dialog similar to Netbean's own "property dialog" that appears when designing. ie. a dialog that contains a table that can be expanded by tree nodes. Something like the dialog on this page, http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-property-editors.html

As far as I can understand, the page I linked to describes a custom editor I can set up for use within netbeans while designing - I'm just looking for a way to doing something similar for my actual application I'm writing. Is there an easy way to do this?

I came across this and have tried it but it doesn't quite work in the same way as the standard Netbeans dialog. weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2008/06/egads_an_actual.html

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about this screenshot: http://platform.netbeans.org/images/tutorials/custom-editors/custom-editor-60-1.png

Or, this screenshot:
http://platform.netbeans.org/images/tutorials/custom-editors/custom-inplace-editor-60.png

Answer (score 1):

This will sound flip... but I am being serious.

The easiest way to do this is to write your app using the NetBeans RCP platform.

You may want to look at the Swing Application Framework, too.

There are a couple SAF samples integrated into NetBeans... You can read about them here: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-saf.html

I could not find a property editor dialog sample, though.

I found a couple other pointers, using this query: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+a+property+editor+dialog+in+swing

Comment: thanks for the response!
i will have to find some info on RCP platform, I have no idea what that is right now. I have started using the Swing Application Framework for the rest of the application.

But yes, I also couldn't find a property editor dialog. The query you mention comes up with links similar to the one i posted, which aren't actually for dialogs I can use in my application (I think), but are property dialogs for use within netbeans itself. I was pretty confused myself. THanks for the reply though. 

Will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look into the [l2fprod](https://web.archive.org/web/20150726091919/http://l2fprod.com/common/) components

[image]
<sub>(source: [l2fprod.com](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/images/PropertySheetPanel-small.gif))</sub>

Comment: thanks also for the reply, another alternative to this weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2008/06/egads_an_actual.htmlwhich I've found has been included in the netbeans 6.5 build. not quite what I'm after, but might be the closest I can get.

Comment: ok, you should add it as answer as well + accept your own then